# Port forwarding/access issue for validator - timed out waiting on receive operation

Tags: validator, node

I am attempting to deploy a validator for the network but having an issue with the client reporting in the log file:

"Received no response at tcp/8801, check your port configuration: timed out waiting on receive operation"

I am getting this for 3 ports. I have setup port forwarding and even tried to disable the firewall completely. The weird thing is if I stop the client and bind the ports manually with another app, I can access them no problem. Could the client be having an issue with binding to the ports or something but reporting that issue in the log file?

Thanks

Comment: I have also tried setting custom ports with

  --gossip-port PORT \
  --dynamic-port-range PORT-PORT \

 But still get the same error in the log file just with the new ports listed as the error.